# Transform JSON and create new one

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I'm working with JSON in Java, and I want to trasnform a JSON I have as entry :

```json
{
   "index":{
      "mutlipleIndices":[
         {
            "index":"languages",
            "values":[
               "English",
               "German"
            ]
         },
         {
            "index":"editors",
            "values":[
               "AC. Renus",
               "Lodiga"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "simpleIndices":[
         {
            "index":"bookName",
            "values":"A song Of Ice and fire"
         },
         {
            "index":"nbPages",
            "valeurs":1600
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

int this :

```json
    {
        "data": { ... Put here the entry JSON ... },
        "flatData": [
            {
                "key": "languages",
                "type": "string",
                "key_type": "languages.string",
                "value_string": ["English", "German"] 
            },
            {
                "key": "editors",
                "type": "string",
                "key_type": "editors.string",
                "value_string": ["AC. Renus", "Lodiga"]
            },
            {
                "key": "bookName",
                "type": "string",
                "key_type": "bookName.string",
                "value_string": "A song Of Ice and fire"
            },
            {
                "key": "nbPages",
                "type": "float",
                "key_type": "nbPages.float",
                "value_float": 1600
            }
        ]
    }
```

My entry JSON is a JsonNode (Jackson library), how can I iterate on that object and create a new one ?
Basically what I thought I'd do is iternate on the entry json, find an entry and transform it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 pojos

1. Mapping the input json (let's call it `MyJsonInput.java`)
2. Mapping the output you want (let's call it `MyOutputObject.java`).

These 2 classes should have fields which matches the json structure.

Create a mapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Read the json and translate it into your object:

```
MyJsonInput myInput = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyJsonInput.class);  //where json is a string with the content of your json file.
```

Now you have a MyJsonInput instance (myInput) containing the json data and you can do your logic to flatten it and fill your `MyOutputObject`.

To get the json string of MyOutputObject instance use:

```
String outputAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myOutputObject);
```

You can also threat your both input and output as a generic `Map<String,Object>` but in my opinion not the best way because it can get very complicated reading and parsing maps containing other maps, and not to mention that you need to cast your data into the appropriate type (string, number etc..)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.21'

-------------------------------------------------

Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("input", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\n" +
    "   \"index\":{\n" +
    "      \"multipleIndices\":[\n" +
    "         {\n" +
    "            \"index\":\"languages\",\n" +
    "            \"values\":[\n" +
    "               \"English\",\n" +
    "               \"German\"\n" +
    "            ]\n" +
    "         },\n" +
    "         {\n" +
    "            \"index\":\"editors\",\n" +
    "            \"values\":[\n" +
    "               \"AC. Renus\",\n" +
    "               \"Lodiga\"\n" +
    "            ]\n" +
    "         }\n" +
    "      ],\n" +
    "      \"simpleIndices\":[\n" +
    "         {\n" +
    "            \"index\":\"bookName\",\n" +
    "            \"values\":\"A song Of Ice and fire\"\n" +
    "         },\n" +
    "         {\n" +
    "            \"index\":\"nbPages\",\n" +
    "            \"values\":1600\n" +
    "         }\n" +
    "      ]\n" +
    "   }\n" +
    "}"));
Map<String, String> dictionaryFinder = new HashMap<>();

// Define a dictionary function, $0 is the function parameter.
dictionaryFinder.put("flatIndices()",
    "$0->map(" +
    "key:index," +
    "type:if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float')," +
    "key_type:concat(index,'.',if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float'))," +
    "value_string:values)");
    
// Define a left concatenate operation to combine two arrays.
dictionaryFinder.put("allIndices",
    "flatIndices(input->index.multipleIndices) <+< flatIndices(input->index.simpleIndices)");
    
ResolverProgress progress = new ResolverProgress("\nProgress:");

// The query is a left concatenate operation to combine two objects.
JsonNode output = jossons.evaluateQueryWithResolver(
    "input->toObject('data') <+< allIndices->toObject('flatData')",
    dictionaryFinder::get, null, progress);
    
// Print result.
System.out.println(output == null ? null : output.toPrettyString());
// Print resolution progress.
System.out.println(String.join("\n", progress.getSteps()));
```

Output

```
{
  "data" : {
    "index" : {
      "multipleIndices" : [ {
        "index" : "languages",
        "values" : [ "English", "German" ]
      }, {
        "index" : "editors",
        "values" : [ "AC. Renus", "Lodiga" ]
      } ],
      "simpleIndices" : [ {
        "index" : "bookName",
        "values" : "A song Of Ice and fire"
      }, {
        "index" : "nbPages",
        "values" : 1600
      } ]
    }
  },
  "flatData" : [ {
    "key" : "languages",
    "type" : "string",
    "key_type" : "languages.string",
    "value_string" : [ "English", "German" ]
  }, {
    "key" : "editors",
    "type" : "string",
    "key_type" : "editors.string",
    "value_string" : [ "AC. Renus", "Lodiga" ]
  }, {
    "key" : "bookName",
    "type" : "string",
    "key_type" : "bookName.string",
    "value_string" : "A song Of Ice and fire"
  }, {
    "key" : "nbPages",
    "type" : "float",
    "key_type" : "nbPages.float",
    "value_string" : 1600
  } ]
}

Progress:
Round 1 : Resolving allIndices from flatIndices(input->index.multipleIndices) <+< flatIndices(input->index.simpleIndices)
Round 1 : Resolving flatIndices(input->index.multipleIndices) from $0->map(key:index,type:if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float'),key_type:concat(index,'.',if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float')),value_string:values)
Round 1 : Resolved flatIndices(input->index.multipleIndices) = Array with 2 elements
Round 2 : Resolving flatIndices(input->index.simpleIndices) from $0->map(key:index,type:if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float'),key_type:concat(index,'.',if(values.isArray(),values[0],values).if(isText(),'string','float')),value_string:values)
Round 2 : Resolved flatIndices(input->index.simpleIndices) = Array with 2 elements
Round 3 : Resolved allIndices = Array with 4 elements
Round 4 : Resolved query result = Object with 2 elements
```